# Numpy how find the index of the third dimension from a three-dimensional array (eg x, y)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using numpy.

Now I have a 3D array:

```
ary = array([[[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]])
```

I want to find the 2D coordinates of `[4, 5, 6]` in it.

The expected result is: `[0,1], [0,4]`.

But if I use `where`, the result is:

```
np.where(s==[4,5,6])
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

So, What can I do to get the results I want like `[0,1], [0,4]`?

Comment: Use : `np.argwhere((ary ==[4,5,6]).all(-1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.where((ary == [4,5,6]).all(axis=-1))
# (array([0, 0]), array([1, 4]))
```

Comment: It would be better to use argwhere instead of where.